# How do I know if other users are accessing the same Databricks Notebook?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

[image: my Databricks Notebook]

How do I know how many other developers are viewing / accessing a notebook in Azure Datbricks ?

Next to recent (clock icon) I can see my team mates user ID sometimes (not shown in image). Does this mean 2 ppl are accessing the notebook at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. All user ids who are accessing notebook at this point can be seen next to the recent icon on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, 2 persons are accessing the notebook at the same time.

> How do I know how many other developers are viewing / accessing a notebook in Azure Datbricks ?

You will see an icon next to (clock icon) with first character of there name as shown below.

**Example:** The below screenshot shows that one person is access the notebook.

[image]